# cannot execute startkde using X2GO client on windows

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, ssh, fedora

I am using a X2GO client on a Windows 7 (64-bit) laptop in order to login to a remote machine running Fedora 20. However, when I try to connect choosing KDE as a session type, I get a "cannot execute startkde" error.

Is there something I need to configure on my laptop or Fedora machine?

Answer (score 14):

This worked for an ubuntu server but may work for fedora/centos. In the session preferences tab of the x2go client, change the "session type" to XFCE

Comment: Changed my session type to X2Go/X11 Desktop Sharing. To remote from windows to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 13):

At this point I'm almost sure the OP has already fixed the issue or just tried another DE. Anyways, just for the record, for other people that may come across this error, this is my experience and how I solved it.

In my case the problem was that the version of KDE I was using didn't have a `startkde` command, at all. Apparently, newer versions of KDE use `startplasma-x11` (or `startplasma-wayland`) instead.

In X2GO, I selected "Custom desktop environment" (or something like that, I'm using another language), then pasted the `startplasma-x11` command in the field. It worked after that.

To check if that's also your problem, try to SSH to the machine, write `which startkde` and, if it fails, then try `which startplasma-x11` and it should return a path. If it does, then you just follow the steps above and it should work.

Comment: `exec` is not needed in X2GO.

Answer (score 6):

Running *sudo yum install @kde* on the remote machine resolved the issue. I was now able to login to the remote machine using X2GO client.

Comment: this really helped me to solve the same issue i encountered in my linux VM.

Comment: No dice for Manjaro KDE since that package doesn't exist anywhere (tried `pacman` and `pamac`).

Answer (score 1):

If the command is not setup up properly in the available PATH,:
then the error like 
**"Cannot run 'startkde'** occours

Please check that the requested application is in the system PATH and that you have the rights to execute it."

you need to login to the super user mode by pressing

```
ctrl + alt + f1
```

Whether the PATH is set or not can be checked by executing

```
which startkde
```

or more generally, 'echo $PATH'

The correct path must be set in /etc/profile or /etc/csh.login, depending on the shell the user is using.

And now when you try to log in from windows desktop after doing all this if error again appears  **Cannot run ‘startkde’**. …

make sure you have the appropriate credentials to access .

Comment: Thanks @Manoj Gautam...i will try out this approach

Answer (score 1):

on ubuntu I had to install XFCE, then select that in the windows client and then it worked.